# limit maximum number of thread in python, but continuously join when one finishes

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

```
import threading
urls=['','','','',...]
for url in urls:
   threading.Thread(target=downloadSaveData, args=(url,)).start()
```

How to limit max thread? Say, `maxThread=4`. After starting of first `4` threads, I don't want to wait till all `4` threads completed, rather continuously adding one thread whenever the total existing threads are less than `4`, i.e. when one thread completes, the next one thread joins.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you want is a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects) which guards access to a resource. Your code will probably look something like the following.

```
import threading

urls=['','','','',...]
semaphore = Semaphore(4)

for url in urls:
   threading.Thread(target=downloadSaveData, args=(url, semaphore, )).start()
```

You just need to modify your `downloadSaveData` to take in a `Semaphore` object and do something along these lines.

```
def downloadSaveDate(url, semaphore):
    with semaphore:
        # perform some logic here
```

Overall I would suggest changing your code to use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) which handles a lot of this stuff under the hood for you.